# How to delete $sce object from $scope angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

If I have this `$scope`

```
$scope.Pages = [
            $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="col-sm-12" style="height:3vh;background-color:#adb5b9;"><a class="DeletePage" onclick="DeletePage()">x</a></div><div class="col-sm-12 Text"><p class="Paragraph" contenteditable="true">Write Your Text Here</p></div>'),
            $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="col-sm-12" style="height:3vh;background-color:#adb5b9;"><a class="DeletePage" ng-click="DeletePage($index)">x</a></div><div class="col-sm-12 Text"><p class="Paragraph" contenteditable="true">Write Your Text Here</p></div>')
        ];
```

How can I delete an object of

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="col-sm-12" style="height:3vh;background-color:#adb5b9;"><a class="DeletePage" ng-click="DeletePage($index)">x</a></div><div class="col-sm-12 Text"><p class="Paragraph" contenteditable="true">Write Your Text Here</p></div>')
```

form `$scope.Pages`
Also I want to access the index of

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="col-sm-12" style="height:3vh;background-color:#adb5b9;"><a class="DeletePage" ng-click="DeletePage($index)">x</a></div><div class="col-sm-12 Text"><p class="Paragraph" contenteditable="true">Write Your Text Here</p></div>')
```

on ng-repeat in `HTML`

Comment: perhaps you want to use the html as template instead. Can set it as template using `$templateCache` . Show how this is being used in view. What is source of this html?

Comment: @charlietfl Check the answer below.

Comment: @charlietfl Although the answer isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var VisualEditor = angular.module("VisualEditor", ["ngSanitize"]);
   VisualEditor.controller('VisualEditorController', function($scope, $sce) {
      $scope.Pages = [
       $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="col-sm-12" style="height:3vh;background-color:#adb5b9;"><a class="DeletePage" onclick="DeletePage($index)">x</a></div><div class="col-sm-12 Text"><p class="Paragraph" contenteditable="true">Write Your Text Here</p></div>'),
       $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="col-sm-12" style="height:3vh;background-color:#adb5b9;"><a class="DeletePage" ng-click="DeletePage($index)">x</a></div><div class="col-sm-12 Text"><p class="Paragraph" contenteditable="true">Write Your Text Here</p></div>')
      ];
      $scope.DeletePage = function(index){
    $scope.Pages.splice(index, 1);
   }
});
```

```html
<div class="row" ng-repeat="pg in Pages track by $index">
      <div class="SinglePage" ng-bind-html="pg">
      </div>
     </div>
```